# PrimeNG dropdown throws error when select one of the options

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm trying to build an angular app with primeng. The problem is in my create component, where I want to use a dropdown for some options to choose.

here is my .ts file with relevant code:

```
//imports
interface Category {
  label: string,
  value: string
}

...

export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {


  categories!: Category[];

  selectedCategory!: Category;

  createForm!: FormGroup;

  // constructor
  ngOnInit() {
    this.categories = [
      { label: 'Scifi', value: 'Scifi' },
      { label: 'Comedy', value: 'Comedy' },
      { label: 'Horror', value: 'Horror' },
      { label: 'Action', value: 'Action' },
      { label: 'Thriller', value: 'Thriller' },
      { label: 'Romance', value: 'Romance' },
      { label: 'Adventure', value: 'Adventure' }
    ];
    console.log("ngOninit called")
    this.createForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      nameOfFilm: ['', Validators.required],
      director: ['', Validators.required],
      category: ['', Validators.required],
      yearMade: ['', Validators.required],
      mainActor: ['', Validators.required],
      length: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

and my html file:

```
<p-card header="You can add new films to the list here" class="flex">
  <div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="createForm" (ngSubmit)="addNewFilm()"> 

      <div class="p-float-label">
        <p-dropdown [options]="categories" [(ngModel)]="categories" placeholder="Select a category"
          formControlName="category" optionLabel="label" [showClear]="true"></p-dropdown>
      </div>
 
    </form>
  </div>
</p-card>
```

there are other inputs field which work fine if I use an input field instead of dropdown.

the error shown is this: `ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`

it shows up when I choose an option from the dropdown field and I cant figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: you are binding array into ngModel, it should be [(ngModel)]="selectedCategory" or "any" type variable

Comment: Shouldn't use a ngModel on the same form field as formControlName, infact Angular display a warning in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[(ngModel)]` on dropdown.